# Two macros on one button

Tags: excel

Is it possible to assign two macros to one button?

Answer (score 5):

You mean, like this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Macro1
    Macro2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want both to run, write a wrapper function that calls them both and just call that.

I wouldn't hard code the call to the second macro at the end of the first since it violates single responsibility plus you might need to use just the first macro in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want both macros to run at the same time, that's probably not possible.  If you want to run one right after the other, simply call the second macro at the end of the first, or as Issun has pointed out, write a wrapper that calls both, and have the button call the wrapper.